# How to snap Steam on Ubuntu to either side of desktop screen?

Tags: 18.04, steam

On Ubuntu 18.04, I can't use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> to snap Steam to the left or right of the screen as I can with other windows.

How can I snap Steam windows to side of a desktop screen?

Comment: what is your screen resolution?

Comment: seems similar problem https://askubuntu.com/q/1088630/739431

Comment: @PRATAP my screen resolution is 1920 x 1080

Comment: Then it could be something with steam app. Ignore above comments.