# Dragging windows to the edge of the screen doesn't snap to that half

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, killall

It also doesn't go fullscreen when I take it to the top edge of the screen.

Is there any process I can try killing before I try restarting my machine?

I already tried `killall nautilus`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't move/snap Nautilus window to occupy left or right half of the 1366x768 screen - is it just me?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088630/cant-move-snap-nautilus-window-to-occupy-left-or-right-half-of-the-1366x768-scr), but I see this only on GNOME sHell in 18.04 LTS.