# Nautilus won't snap to left or right

Tags: shortcut-keys, nautilus, 21.04

I am using ubuntu 21.04 and when I use shortcut in nautilus file manager super+left or super+right it won't snap to left or right i don't know why it is happening, but it is working in ubuntu 20.04

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-fixed false`

Comment: You need to enable autohide dock

Comment: Look [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1089802/1460940)

Comment: yes it does solve the problem, because my screen is 1366x768 but I have to autohide the dock.