# Window snapping shortcuts "Super+Left" and "Super+Right" no longer work after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: window, shortcuts, 22.04

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to snap a window no longer work.

Is there a way to get them back?

Comment: Is that for all windows, or just Files/Nautilus? See some similar threads: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415955/superright-left-no-longer-works-with-nautilus-windows-on-22-04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088630/cant-move-snap-nautilus-window-to-occupy-left-or-right-half-of-the-1366x768-scr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These shortcut keys should be enabled by default. You may reset these keyboard bindings to their default settings with the following commands:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-left
gsettings reset org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-right
```