# Super+right/left no longer works with nautilus windows on 22.04

Tags: nautilus, 22.04

I'm on a fresh 22.04 install.

Super+arrow_key maximizes, minimizes, or snaps a window left or right, resizing it to half the screen.

This works with all windows I've tried (web browsers, terminal, image viewer...) except for nautilus. Weirdly, **super+up/down works fine** (to maximize/minimize), **but not super+left/right**. That does nothing.

I've tried disabling the side panel or resizing the dock, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088630/cant-move-snap-nautilus-window-to-occupy-left-or-right-half-of-the-1366x768-scr), to no avail.

Is anyone having the same issue?

Comment: You tagged "Unity"? Do you use the Unity desktop? I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: @vanadium Oh, no. I thought Unity was the default, but I see that's no longer the case. I removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same symptoms on a fresh install of 18.04.6.

Super + Arrows were working fine on a previous machine under the same Ubuntu version.

apt show says my system is running:
Package: nautilus
Version: 1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.5