# Ubuntu 22.04 - Keyboard shortcut to open new window

Tags: shortcut-keys, ubuntu-gnome

Super+(number) can be used to interact with programs on the dock. On my system, for example, nautilus is the first, so I can use Super+1 to either

- open a new window of nautilus if none are open, or
- switch to an open nautilus window.

On 20.04 I used to be able to open a new window, even if others were open, by pressing Super+shift+(number). But on 22.04, this no longer works ([along with other functionalities I found extremely useful](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415955/superright-left-no-longer-works-with-nautilus-windows-on-22-04)).

Is there any way to restore this shortcut?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. For me, Super+Shift+2 opens an additional nautilus menu.

Comment: @vanadium Just like that, by default? It's certainly not working for me...

Comment: What is your output of "gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-1`?

Comment: ['<Shift><Super>1']

Comment: The setting is as expected, so the issue is not due to changed settings.